# How to run two statements in mysqli_query

Tags: php

I need to run two statements to return the data I need. The below code will return all needed except the count column which can be retrieved from a different table.

How can I run these two statements in the same code to retrieve the count as well?

**Here is the code I have:**

```
 <?php

  $query =  "SELECT * from $CLIENTS_DATABASE order by id DESC";

  if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    ?>

        <tr>

        <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["url"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["secret"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["count"]; ?> </td>

        </tr>

    <?php    
       }
           mysqli_free_result($result);
      }  
    ?>
```

The other statement that the count data I need is this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count from visits where id_client='$result[id]'"
```

Thanks for your time and any help you can provide.

Comment: Could it be accomplished by using a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`? I can't tell from your example if that makes sense with your desired result

Answer (score 0):

Join the two queries.

```
$query = "SELECT order.*, IFNULL(c.count, 0) AS count
          FROM $CLIENTS_DATABASE AS order
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_client, COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM visits
                GROUP BY id_client) AS c
          ON c.id_client = order.id
          ORDER BY order.id DESC";
```

Comment: this did not do anything.

Comment: Are you sure you should be matching the two tables using `order.id = visits.id_client`? Maybe it should be `order.id_client = visits.id_client`?

Comment: I've changed to `LEFT JOIN` so you'll get rows with `count = 0` when there's no match.